# SavedStateHandle kotlin always receiving null

Tags: android, kotlin

I need a Factory to support Viewmodel WITH ARGUMENTS. I tried to implement the class which is commended "AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory". I applied the trouble in the short way.

I don't know if I am failing at ShopFragment. Some ideas please.
I am working with HandleSavedState and a customizable ModelFactory which receive parameters,  extending AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory, but I am not currently be able to SAVE VALUE.

!! BY THE WAY: I don't know if this line(ShopFragment.kt) is correct:
`ShopViewModelFactory(requireNotNull(requireActivity()).application, this, quantity, idupdate)` maybe it is

I had tried harder but always receive null in Log. I don't want Inject dependencies with some responses that I have seen like "Hilt"

dependencies
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.5.0-alpha02"

ViewModelfactory.kt

```
class ShopViewModelFactory(
    val application: Application,
    val owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
    val quantity: Int, val idupdate: Int
) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, null){
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create( key: String, modelClass: Class<T>,
                                          handle: SavedStateHandle ): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ShopViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return ShopViewModel(application, handle, quantity,idupdate) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unable to construct SHOPviewmodel")
    }
}
```

In the Fragment: ShopFragment.kt

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle? ): View? {
    bind = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false)

    var quantity = ShopFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).quantity
    var idupdate = ShopFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).idproduct
    var factory = ShopViewModelFactory(requireNotNull(requireActivity()).application,
            this,
            quantity,
            idupdate)
    vmShop =ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(ShopViewModel::class.java)
```

In ShopViewModel.kt:

```
class ShopViewModel (application: Application,
                    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
                    quantity: Int,  idupdate: Int): ViewModel() {

private val memoria2 : MutableLiveData<String> = savedStateHandle.getLiveData("user","init ")
   init{
       Log.i("DICE","RECUPERADO ${memoria2}")
     addToCart()
   }

   private fun addToCart(){
   memoria2.value += "Some data"
      // that previous sentence suppose to save persist data 
// !!if I add savedStateHandle.set("user", memoria2.value) still is not working
   }
}
```

This supposed to initialize if savedInstanceState.value is null:
savedStateHandle.getLiveData("user","init ")

Expected response:

a. I/DICE RECUPERADO init Some data

b. I/DICE RECUPERADO init Some data Some data

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a `SavedStateHandle` and `getLiveData` for a particular key, you're not supposed to set the value on that `LiveData` - you're supposed to set it on the `SavedStateHandle` using the same key. That way, the data is stored, and the `LiveData` updates automatically (because `getLiveData` links it to the stored state)

So you want to do it this way:

```
private fun addToCart(){
   savedStateHandle["user"] = "Some data"
}
```

and it should just work!

Remember that `SavedStateHandle`s are lost when the app is explicitly closed. They only maintain the state while the app is running, so it can survive things like Activities getting destroyed, or the app getting closed in the background and recreated by the system - it's like `savedInstanceState` in an `Activity` or `Fragment`. If you need to store data between sessions, you need to persist it in something like `SharedPreferences` or a database

Comment: In first place Than You for Your Answer. Now:
(1)- savedStateHandle["user"] = "Some data" Still not working. That supposed to be in theory  memoria2.value = "Some data" and that sentence should do = persist data if I understood.

(2)- I applied in some different ways the same key and nothing.
I used to navigate to DetailFragment(detail of product) and then return into ShopFragment and 0.

(3)- I would like to use this method of SavedStateHandle but it look so worst to apply

Comment: About SavedInstanceState :  savedstatehandler is capable of restore the state viewmodel and Google introduced in 2019 . I just readed in other post